# How do I port forward in dropbear ssh?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have been using openSSH for a little bit and just learned the basics of port forwarding in OpenSSH. I own some equipment that has dropbear installed on it but it seems the options are different. The equipment has an internal webpage operating on port 443 and I would like to forward that to another PC securely.

Comment: do you wan tcp forward proxy (like -L) or reverse (like -R)

Comment: Yes but in dropbear I dont get those options

Comment: wich one? the -L or the -R. which version do you use, how is it compiled?

Comment: In particular dropbear V2018.76. I will mainly be using -R. I’m not sure about how it’s compiled. How would I find that out if I need to know?

Comment: Dropbear and its corresponding client, supports the tcp proxy out of the box, with -L and -R.  so if it doesn't work, its probably compiled out.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/dropbear
I’m reading the manual for this and don’t see the -R or -L options. So I feel as if it wasn’t ever in to be compiled out.

Comment: according to the changelog of dropbear https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/CHANGES there is a -L and -R tcp proxy, according to https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html, 'Features can easily be disabled when compiling to save space'

Answer (score 0):

Port-forwarding requires the ssh client and ssh server to interoperate, and of course for the feature to be present and allowed in both. At *build time* Dropbear has 4 distinct settings for this

```
#define DROPBEAR_CLI_LOCALTCPFWD 1
#define DROPBEAR_CLI_REMOTETCPFWD 1
#define DROPBEAR_SVR_LOCALTCPFWD 1
#define DROPBEAR_SVR_REMOTETCPFWD 1
```

These are all set by default in the official (current dropbear-2022.82) source. AFAICT every public release since 2003 has had some form of TCP forwarding support (but not necessarily enabled when it was built).

Usefully, these options control both the feature itself, *and* whether the feature is documented in the `-h` help output—if the relevant options are omitted from the help output then they were omitted from the build.

With Dropbear server you should be able to run `dropbear -h` or (`sshd -h` if it has been renamed), the presence of the `-j` and/or `-k` options indicate `DROPBEAR_SVR_LOCALTCPFWD` and `DROPBEAR_SVR_REMOTETCPFWD` respectively were set at build time.

With Dropbear client you should run `dbclient -h` (or `ssh -h`), the presence of the `-L` and/or `-R` indicate `DROPBEAR_CLI_LOCALTCPFWD` and `DROPBEAR_CLI_REMOTETCPFWD` respectively were set at build time.

(If the binaries were renamed you can confirm their identity with the `-V` option.)

Finally, for Dropbear server it must be started *without* the `-j` or `-k` options to allow it to observe client requests for local and remote forwarding respectively.

If all of the above is as expected (specifically the capabilities and run-time options of the target system Dropbear ssh server) you should then be able to do something like one of:

```
ssh -L10443:127.0.0.1:443 dropbearhost
ssh -L10443:x.x.x.x:443 dropbearhost
```

where localhost:10443 (e.g. https://localhost:10443/  on the initiating system will forward to 127.0.0.1:443 on dropbearhost (or x.x.x.x:443 with an alternate IP if the web server is bound to a specific address). If SNI is enforced, then adding the virtualhost name to the `hosts` file on the initiating system should fix that (and might also be required if the web content uses redirects).

---

If you happen to be building Dropbear, you change those build options by hand after running `configure`:

```
grep TCPFWD default_options.h >> localoptions.h
```

and amend, setting them to 0 or 1 as required. (Note though in older versions these defines were named, set and used slightly differently.)